# External dependencies in Android library

Tags: android, maven, kotlin, gradle, dependencies

I have own Android library which use 2 external libraries:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.4")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0")
```

When I use my libary in another project app crashes and shows error related to these two libraries.
How I can generate .aar file of my library which will include these two libraries.
Right now I need to add these dependiencies manually in my another project and I want to avaoid that

Comment: "Right now I need to add these dependiencies manually in my another project and I want to avaoid that" -- replace `implementation` with `api`.

Comment: I still need to implement these libraries, otherwise app crashes.

Comment: If the app and the library are in separate Android Studio projects, then you should be publishing the library via a Maven repository, such as `mavenLocal()`. That will publish a POM file with metadata about dependencies, the same as the libraries that you are using. The app will be able to load those transitive dependencies, just as it is for other libraries that the app is using.

Comment: If I understood correctly. When my library contains another external libraries I should publish my library via Maven and then when I will use it in another project everthing should work fine.

Comment: Correct. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#view-dependency-tree and https://developer.android.com/studio/publish-library/upload-library for more.